# Access to the path is denied in Docker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to host an ASPNET.MVC application on Docker using a useful article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/deployment/docker-aspnetmvc), I followed all the step as mentioned in the article but when access the site I am getting an error Folder name BinaryData is not accessible, this folder contains JSON file and that is used by the application. I am using Docker Version 17.12.0-ce-win47 (15139)

Docker File

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet
COPY ./MVCDOCKER/ /inetpub/wwwroot
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After hrs of googling, I have managed to solve this issue here is my updated DockerFile.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet
RUN New-Item c:\MVCAPP -type directory
WORKDIR /navientdxa
COPY ./DXADOCKER/ .
RUN Remove-WebSite -Name 'Default Web Site' 
RUN New-Website -Name 'DXADOCKER' -Port 80 -PhysicalPath 'c:\MVCAPP' -ApplicationPool '.NET v4.5'
```